# Access TYPO3 Plugin Version Number in Extbase/Fluid

Tags: typo3, extbase, fluid, typo3-8.x

I am developing a TYPO3 Frontend Plugin.

How can I access the version number (defined in ext_emconf.php of the plugin) in Extbase/Fluid ?

Answer (score 0):

In your Controller you could use the `ExtensionManagementUtility``

`\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::getExtensionVersion($extkey)`

See here: https://api.typo3.org/typo3cms/current/html/class_t_y_p_o3_1_1_c_m_s_1_1_core_1_1_utility_1_1_extension_management_utility.html#a8fd6ee32516ca18e806041f84048c63d

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the hint.

I managed to get the version in my Extbase Controller like this:

```
$version = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::getExtensionVersion($this->request->getControllerExtensionKey());
```